# Variance Inflation Factors (VIFs) on model vs covariates themselves

Tags: r, variance-inflation-factor

I am confused on which type of "object" do the VIF functions operate.

Let me give two examples, which are confusing me. The VIFs from the `car` and `AED` libraries are purportedly doing a very similar thing. However:

1) The `vif()` command in the R package `car` calculates VIFs based on the **model** (for example, a linear model). I have no issue with interpreting the results.

But this is clearly different from the following:

2) Zuur et al. 2009 (Mixed effects models and extensions in ecology with R) have produced their `corvif` function within the `AED` package. There, the VIFs seem to be calculated based on the **covariates** themselves (i.e. *before* the model is even fitted).

Here is an example from their book (I am not including actual data here, but that's not the point anyway):

```
library(AED); data(Tbdeer)
Z <- cbind(Tbdeer$OpenLand, Tbdeer$ScrubLand,
Tbdeer$QuercusPlants, Tbdeer$QuercusTrees,
Tbdeer$ReedDeerIndex, Tbdeer$EstateSize,
Tbdeer$Fenced)
corvif(Z)
```

And that's what is confusing me. Also, the `vif()` command from the `car` package does not seem to work unless the object is a model.

(I realise this is somewhat related to R and coding, but I thought it has a more general statistical relevance, so I posted it here)

Any thoughts?

Comment: This the explanation in the [website](http://www.highstat.com/book2.htm): "In the book we use the package AED to load data. However, we haven given up compiling a new version of the AED package each time a new R version comes out. Therefore we no longer provide AED." Is there any other way to get the package?

Comment: Yes, on the same page (http://www.highstat.com/book2.htm), they provide the code, saying: "To run the corvif function and the pairplot with the Pearson correlation coefficients, download the file HighstatLibV6.R (use right-mouse click and Save As), save it to your computer and in R type: > source("C:/YourDirectory/HighstatLibV6.R")."
  
http://www.highstat.com/Book2/HighstatLibV6.R

Comment: The functions return same results. You don't need to fit the model to calculate vif, if that was your question. You only need the list of independent variables.

Comment: Yes, that was my question. But when I tried that via "vif" function in "car" library, I got an error. It says "Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors".

Comment: I think that is the coding part of the question. The documentation of the `vif` in `car` shows, "an object that responds to coef, vcov, and model.matrix, such as an lm or glm object" should be used. That might not be the case for other similar/equivalent functions. It is the authors' decision about how to write the functions.

Comment: OK, but then this leads me back to my original question or rather my point: that these two functions are doing different things, as one does it on the fitted model, while the other can do it on the variables alone. What am I missing?
Also, didn't you say that the functions return the same results? Did you try them both and they both gave you the same result?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53720/discussion-between-t-e-g-and-tilen).

Comment: @T.E.G., given that you helped me with an answer to my question, I just wondered whether you (or I) should post the conclusions in the form of an asnwer here...? Or is that not needed (desired)? Just trying to grasp the proper rules of procedure. :)

Comment: It is not required, but you can answer your own question as it is explained [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 3):

The Variance Inflation Factor (VIF) can be defined as

$$\frac{1}{1-R_i^2}$$ where $R_i^2$ is the R-squared value for the regression of the $i$-th regressor on the other regressors.

So all you need to know are the regressors and not the observed outcomes. The object on which the VIF functions operate is the [regressor-matrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_matrix).

---

The R-code below shows four methods that all work the same and return a vector

```
15.373833 21.620241  9.832037  3.374620 15.164887 7.527958  4.965873  4.648487  5.357452  7.908747
```

The four methods are

1. The `corvif` function from the aed package (since this is discontinued a copy of the code is added below).

   This function uses just the regressor-matrix.
2. The `vif` function from the car package.

   This function *also* uses the regressor-matrix. But, it does this indirectly. You need to give an object to the function from which the regressor-matrix can be obtained using functions `model.matrix`, `coef`, or `vcov`.
3. The computation using $$\frac{1}{1-R_i^2}$$
4. An alternative computation with $$\text{Var}(X_j) \cdot  [(X^tX)^{-1}]_{jj} \cdot (n-1)$$ where $n$ is the number of observations.

code:

```
### data and properties like number of parameters p and number of observations n
### 
data = datasets::mtcars
Y <- data$mpg
Z <- cbind(data$cyl, data$disp, data$hp, data$drat, data$wt, data$qsec, data$vs, data$am, data$gear, data$carb)
n = length(Y)
p = length(Z[1,])

### design matrix / regressor-matrix
Zp <- cbind(rep(1,n),Z)  
### linear model containing the design matrix
mod <- lm(Y ~ . , data = as.data.frame(Z))
          
### aed::corvif
corvif(Z)

### car::vif
car::vif(mod)

### computation with R-squared of regressing regressor vs other regressors
sapply(1:p, FUN = function(i) { 
  mod <- lm(Z[,i] ~ 1+Z[,-i])
  1/(1-summary(mod)$r.squared)
})

### computation with inverse of model matrix (X^tX)^-1
apply(Z,2,var) *diag(solve(t(Zp) %*% Zp))[-1] * (n-1)
```

---

Code for `corvif`

```
corvif <- function(dataz) {
  dataz <- as.data.frame(dataz)
  #correlation part
  #cat("Correlations of the variables\n\n")
  #tmp_cor <- cor(dataz,use="complete.obs")
  #print(tmp_cor)
  
  #vif part
  form    <- formula(paste("fooy ~ ",paste(strsplit(names(dataz)," "),collapse=" + ")))
  dataz   <- data.frame(fooy=1,dataz)
  lm_mod  <- lm(form,dataz)
  
  cat("\n\nVariance inflation factors\n\n")
  print(myvif(lm_mod))
}


#Support function for corvif. Will not be called by the user
myvif <- function(mod) {
  v <- vcov(mod)
  assign <- attributes(model.matrix(mod))$assign
  if (names(coefficients(mod)[1]) == "(Intercept)") {
    v <- v[-1, -1]
    assign <- assign[-1]
  } else warning("No intercept: vifs may not be sensible.")
  terms <- labels(terms(mod))
  n.terms <- length(terms)
  if (n.terms < 2) stop("The model contains fewer than 2 terms")
  if (length(assign) > dim(v)[1] ) {
    diag(tmp_cor)<-0
    if (any(tmp_cor==1.0)){
      return("Sample size is too small, 100% collinearity is present")
    } else {
      return("Sample size is too small")
    }
  }
  R <- cov2cor(v)
  detR <- det(R)
  result <- matrix(0, n.terms, 3)
  rownames(result) <- terms
  colnames(result) <- c("GVIF", "Df", "GVIF^(1/2Df)")
  for (term in 1:n.terms) {
    subs <- which(assign == term)
    result[term, 1] <- det(as.matrix(R[subs, subs])) * det(as.matrix(R[-subs, -subs])) / detR
    result[term, 2] <- length(subs)
  }
  if (all(result[, 2] == 1)) {
    result <- data.frame(GVIF=result[, 1])
  } else {
    result[, 3] <- result[, 1]^(1/(2 * result[, 2]))
  }
  invisible(result)
}
#END VIF FUNCTIONS
```